# Kotlin - The method returns how many elements meet the condition

Tags: kotlin, lambda, linked-list, iteration, higher-order-functions

I'm struggling to get this working:

**Implement the method countWhere (condition: (T) -> Boolean): Int. The method returns how many elements meet the condition (state).
Here is an example of how it can be used:**

*NOTE: I can't change the fun main stuff.*

```
fun main () {
val list = LinkedList <String> ()
list . addFirst ("Apple")
list . addFirst ("Banana")
list . addFirst ("Bear")
val fruitStartsWithB = list. countWhere {element ->
element. starts with ("B")
}
println (fruitStartsWithB) // fruitsStartsWithB is 2 because there are two items in the list that go into "B".
}
```

this is what causing me troubles:

```
    fun countWhere(condition: (T) -> Boolean): Int {
        var count: Int = 0

        forEach { if (this == condition)  count++ }

        return count
    }
```

my return is 0. My return has to be 2. Where is my mistake and how do I fix it?

**This is all the code I have:**

```
class LinkedList <T>: Iterable<T> {
    data class Node <T>( val data : T, var next : Node <T>?)
    private var first : Node <T>? = null
    var isSorted = true

     fun isEmpty() = first == null

     fun addFirst(data: T) {
        first = Node(data, first)
        isSorted = false
    }

    fun getFirst(): T = get(0)

    fun get(n: Int): T {
        if (n < 0 ) throw IndexOutOfBoundsException ()
        var run  = first
        var count = 0
        while (count < n && run != null) {
            run = run.next
            count++
        }
        return run?.data ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException ()
    }

    fun clear () {
        first = null                // Clear
        isSorted = true             // Clear
    }

//    fun size (): Int{
//        var run = first
//        var count = 0
//        while (run != null) {
//            count++
//            run = run.next
//        }
//        return count
//    }

    fun getOrNull(index: Int): T? {
        if (index < 0 ) return null
        var run  = first
        var count = 0
        while (count < index && run != null) {
            run = run.next
            count++
    }
        return run?.data ?: null
    }

    fun addLast (data: T){
        if (isEmpty()) addFirst(data) else {
            var runPointer = first
            while (runPointer?.next != null) {
                runPointer = runPointer.next
            }
            runPointer?.next = Node(data, null)
        }
        isSorted = false
    }

    fun forEach(action: (T) -> Unit) {
        for (i in this ) action(i)
    }

    fun size (): Int{
        var count = 0

        forEach { count ++ }

        return count
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> =  object: Iterator <T> {

        private var run = first

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean = run!= null

        override fun next(): T {
            val res = run?.data ?: throw NoSuchElementException()
            run = run?.next
            return res
        }
    }

    fun countWhere(condition: (T) -> Boolean): Int {
        var count: Int = 0

        forEach { if (condition(it))  count++ }

        return count
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, Kotlin stdlib provides such extension method (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html), so you may just call it `list.count { it.startsWith("B") }`

Comment: I can't change the actual calls in the main method. It's something in the countWhere method I'm missing

Answer (score 2):

you have to invoke your lambda:

```
fun countWhere(condition: (T) -> Boolean): Int {
    var count: Int = 0

    forEach { if (condition(it))  count++ }

    return count
}
```

Comment: my return is still 0

Comment: well, also there is no element which starts with "B" in your list :) Only with "b"

Comment: yeah, I've translated the actual code. It should be fine now. Still the return is 0

Comment: that's strange. For me it returns 2 https://pl.kotl.in/OsIvayXHO

Comment: **your methods name is** "fun <T> List<T>.countWhere(condition: (T) -> Boolean): Int" **whereas mine is** fun countWhere(condition: (T) -> Boolean): Int

Comment: I just added the whole code, it might help you helping me :D

Comment: You won't believe what I was missing... It worked now. Thanks. Lol